# how to update same file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have the following scenario:

I have an application developed in Python 2.7 that has only a file and used the [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki) to generate the torque it. But I need to deploy a autoupdate this file.

This application runs as a service and managed by [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) in Windows

How best can I perform this update?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I decided that this executable ensure that an available update, existing, download an updater that performs the procedures, and when the finishing process initializes the service.

When you start service, it deletes the updater.